# How to get Entity at the servlet using MultipartEntity?

Tags: java, android, servlets

If i Upload a file to my servlet like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.tumblr.com/api/write");

try 
{
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));
    entity.addPart("data", new FileBody(image));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} 
catch (IOException e) {}
```

How can I retrieve the content at the servlet?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  IOException 
{
     request.???
}
```

- I'm using Google App Server as my Servlet API

Comment: Just search Stackoverflow - hundreds of questions/answers covering file upload + servlets do already exist!

Comment: Read http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

Comment: @home The first step is searching the web and this site, and you should assume the one that's asking here already done that. I think that sending me to search by my self is not the spirit of this site. so at least you should have post any link instead just comment go search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the version of your Servlet Container or Server or Engine **< 3.0** (like 2.5 or earlier) , you may want to take advantage of the third-party Library [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). Although the file implied an use for uploaded Files, it also deals effectually with uploaded posted Data from POST-Methods like it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824).

the Servlet API, from the version 3.0 offers some calls in oder to deal with posted Data, with was sent within a POST-Request. the only requirement is that the MIME-Type encoding of your entity content is "[multipart/form-data](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart%28java.lang.String%29)".

then your can retrieve each "part" of your content using either:

1. [getPart(String partName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart%28java.lang.String%29): where "partName" is the name of a part of your Multicontent entity.

   ```
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  IOException 
   {
       String partName = "type"; // or "data"
       Part part = request.getPart(partName);

       // read your StringBody type
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(part.getInputStream()));
       String line ="";

       while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
       {
           // do Something with a line
           System.out.println(line);

       }

       // or with a binary Data
       partName="data";
       part = request.getPart(partName);

       // read your FileBody data
       InputStream is = part.getInputStream();
       // do Something with you byte data

       is.read();
       // is.read(b);
       // ..

   }
   ```
2. [getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29):

it achieves the same results as getPart(partName), whereas the given data here a collection of all part of the sent data. to retrieve each par of the Part of this collection, just use thread-safe iteration over the collection:

```
Iterator<Part> iterator = request.getParts().iterator();
       Part parts = null;
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       parts = (Part) iterator.next();
          //rest of the code block removed
       }
    }
```

Because the getPart()/getParts() only works beginning at the Servlet 3.0 version, you'll make sure to use the supporting Servlet container and/or upgrade your current Servlet Container. some Server or Servlet container that supports 3.0:

1. [tomcat 7.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html):
2. [Jboss Web](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb)
3. [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/)

Comment: I'm using Google App Engine so I don't know If i can use Servlet 3.0 or how, but i'll try to find for details about it. thanks.

Comment: GAE Servlet API version is 2.5 so I guess I won't be able to use this.
But thanks.

Comment: @Rami: i edited my answer according to your problem. if you read again, you'll find a link to quick presentation to a third party library "Apache Commons FileUpload" dealing with your situation. enjoy!!